# parsing url from embed code in php?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, url, embed

I want to parse the url from the embed code :

> `<embed src="http://url/player.swf" width="360" height="240" />`

It's extracted from my db and put into a variable... How do i parse the url??

any help appreciated..

Edit:

I should probably add that the url in the embed code wnt always be the same (on different pages)... as it's been taking from the db

Comment: instead of saving complete `<embed>` tag you could consider to save url only

Answer (score 0):

start by exploding the string

```
$theString = '<embed src="http://url/player.swf" width="360" height="240" />';

$arrString = explode('"', $theString);

$yourURL = $arrString[1];
```

Comment: Obviously it could be a more sophisticated script.  Simply test the result - no "http", try the next value in the array. This was just an idea to get gazzamc started.

Comment: Thanks so much worked perfectly.. been tearing my hair out for hrs on this... tnx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$str = '<embed src="http://url/player.swf" width="360" height="240" />';

if (preg_match('!<embed[^>]+src="([^"]+)"[^>]+/>!', $str, $matches)) {
    $src = $matches[1];
    print_r(parse_url($src));
}
```

Comment: see the url wnt always be the same on every page... would <?php
$str = $embed;

if (preg_match('!<embed[^>]+src="([^"]+)"[^>]+/>!', $str, $matches)) {
    $src = $matches[1];
    print_r(parse_url($src));
}
work?? the embed code will be coming from the db and will be different..

Comment: If I understand your question correclty: Yes, it will also match different urls, for this is the main reason to use regular expressions. Of course, its your responsibility to change the code according to your needs, this is just an example of how it could be solved.